# Electron absorption by materials

Tags: particle-physics

Is it possible to define whether or not a material has absorbed electrons after it has collided with an accelerated electron beam? If so is it possible to calculate where they gathered after the collision?

Comment: do you mean an individual electron?  What size of material?  Macroscopic or microscopic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to define whether or not a material has absorbed electrons after it has collided with an accelerated electron beam?

It will depend on a large number of conditions: energy of beam, the type of material, in general the boundary conditions of the experiment.

> If so is it possible to calculate where they gathered after the collision?

In general if a neutral material absorbs electrons, it will become negatively charged and there are instruments developed that can measure charge. It will depend on the type of material and the topology of the situation/experiment. Metals have charge on the surface, for example.

It is not advisable to expose random material, [including humans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8330958), to  accelerator beams.

Comment: Things may also get positively charged when the number of Auger electrons, secondary electrons, etc is larger than the number of incident electrons. Indeed, this depends on the experiment.